# Running Cron job on Amazon Instance with Bitnami

Tags: cron, amazon-ec2, bitnami

I have a python file programmed that makes an automatic backup of my Amazon instance.

In this instance I have Mautic Bitnami installed.

I have tried to run the file from the next line, directly in the terminal and it works correctly.

```
python3 /home/bitnami/aws/snapshot_script.py --volume-ids = vol-07701xxxxxxxxxx --expiry-days = 7
```

(Create a backup that expires in 7 days.)

This is how the `snapshot_script.py` file begins:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

The problem starts when I want to execute the line of code in a cron job, it does not work.

I have tried many things without getting results, for example:

- Change `python` to `/usr/bin/python3`
- Change `python` to `//usr/bin/env python3`
- Use `your bitnami -s` when starting the cron
- `sudo crontab -l` to see if it is executed (yes it does)
- `sudo adduser bitnami daemon` recommended on the web
- Copy the structure of the other crons:

  /5 * * * * su daemon -s /bin/sh -c "/opt/bitnami/php/bin/php -q /opt/bitnami/apps/mautic/htdocs/app/console mautic:segments:update" #mautic-segments-cron

the results of `locate python` are:

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 
/usr/bin/python3.5m 
/usr/lib/python2.7 
/usr/lib/python3.5 
/etc/python3.5 
/usr/local/lib/python3.5 
/usr/include/python3.5m 
/usr/share/
```

*How should I proceed?*

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! **;-)** Could you please review my **[edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1131730/revisions)** and also review the [editing help](/editing-help) to improve the readability of your questions in the future... **;-)**

Comment: If you want to run a cron job as a specific user, then rather than using root's crontab (`sudo crontab ...`) and jumping through hoops with `su` and shells, I'd suggest using the system-wide crontab file `/etc/crontab` (or a custom file in `/etc/cron.d`) where you can specify the username directly as an additional field after the time spec.

Comment: Hello,

Thank you very much for your help.

When you install the cronjob in "/etc/crontab" everything works correctly.

I really appreciate your help.